# Laravel post : routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

So, i started with laravel. Tried with making a form post to the same page.
Here's what i have so far,

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function () {
   Route::post('contactus', 'HomeController@sendEmail');
});
```

**hello.php**

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@sendEmail'))?>
input fields here
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
```

**HomeController**

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

public function sendEmail()
{
    print_r($_POST);exit;
}
```

**Problem**: Form gets posted to the url **public/contactus**

Can someone point out which really stupid thing, i am doing?

Comment: "Laravel post : total newbie" is not a question, please correct your question with a meaningfull title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::post('/', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',  // csrf filter
    'uses' => 'HomeController@sendEmail' // the controller action to be used
));
```

**hello.php**

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@sendEmail')) ?>
      <!-- input fields here -->
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
```

**HomeController.php**

```
Public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

public function sendEmail()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    print_r($data);
    // return the same view but with posted fields in the $data array
    return View::make('hello', $data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@sendEmail');
```

Hello.blade.php

```
@if(isset($post))
    {{$post}}
@endif
{{Form::open()}}
{{Form::text('sometext')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

HomeController

```
Public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

public function sendEmail()
{

$post = Input::all();
return View::make('hello', array('post' => $post));
}
```

Comment: @Winstar - The page just gets reloaded.

**Headers**
    Request URL:http://localhost/test/huge/public
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

Comment: @SwarajGiri You should use blade for you php file (just change the name). I edited so you should see your post data

Comment: @Winstar - Nope, still the same headers